# Cache Clean setup is not working

Tags: magento2, cache, file-permissions, http-error-500, magento2.4.2

After running the bin/magento cache:clean the setup gets 500 Error i saw the log means

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Zend_Cache_Exception: cache_dir
> "/var/www/html/var/page_cache" is not writable in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php:209\nStack
> trace:\n#0
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(180):
> Zend_Cache::throwException()\n#1
> /var/www/html/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-file/File.php(87):
> Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir()\n#2
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
> Cm_Cache_Backend_File->__construct()\n#3
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
> Zend_Cache::_makeBackend()\n#4
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156):
> Zend_Cache::factory()\n#5
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Cache/Frontend/Adapter/Zend.php(38):
> Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\Factory->Magento\Framework\App\Cache\Frontend\{closure}()\n#6
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(121):
> Magento\Framework\Cache\Frontend\Adapte in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php on
> line 209

After giving the directory access it is showinf the below error

> ReflectionException: Class Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor does
> not exist in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php:24
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php(24):
> ReflectionClass->__construct() #1
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(54):
> Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() #2
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(48):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() #3
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() #4
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(237):
> Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() #5
> /var/www/html/pub/index.php(28):
> Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->createApplication() #6 {main}

After run the **setup:di:compile** it is working. Iam running the command in as **superuser** (sudo su), and the file owner is ubuntu is there any problem in the working method. Iam using the magento 2.4.2

Answer (score 0):

You should not execute any of the magento CLI commands (bin/magento) under root user, instead **you should use the same user as the webserver (usually www-data)**. Otherwise you the webserver will not be able to access the generated resources properly or delete them.

Consider reading https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/prereq/file-sys-perms-over.html and make sure you apply the directions properly.